# Why not all the items in the List that not contains the string not removed from the List?

Tags: c#

```
var g = urls;
if (g.Count > 1)
{
     for(int i = g.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
     {
          if (!g[i].Contains("Test"))
          {
                g.RemoveAt(i);
          }
     }
 }
```

I create a copy of the List then checking for specific string in each item but there are 23 items left in g one of them is not containing the word "Test" but was not removed it's the first item in the list at index 0.

Comment: Probably this: `i > 0`

Comment: Modifying a collection while iterating over it might cause side effects and sometimes, exceptions.

Comment: @SelmanGenç This specific case is fine and safe, however

Comment: @canton7 yes it seems fine in this case, but I'm just saying :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your for loop is not touching element present at index 0, to fix this issue update your for loop to

```
  for(int i = g.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {                        //^^^^ This is missing in your code
        if (!g[i].Contains("Test"))
        {
               g.RemoveAt(i);
         }
  }
```

To make it more readable, you can traverse from start instead of reverse traversal and store expected element of `g` into a new list.

```
  var result = new List<string>();
  for(int i = 0; i < g.Count; i++)
  {
        if (g[i].Contains("Test"))
        {
               result.Add(g[i]);
         }
  }
```

To make it more elegant you can use Linq [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-clause) clause,

```
var result = g.Where(x => x.Contains("Test")).ToList();
```

If you are looking for a solution which actually update input list (in Your case it is `g`), then you can use solution suggested by [@canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086121/canton7),

```
g.RemoveAll(item => !item.Contains("Test"))
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", g));
```

[.RemoveAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0)

---

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gt7DXw)

Comment: No, you can't traverse from start, because removing entries changes the indexes of all the elements following the removed item.

Answer (score -1):

```
var g = urls.Where(u => u.Contains("Test")).ToList();
```

Comment: If `g` is a `List<T>`, and you want to modify it in-place rather than creating a new list, you can also do `g.RemoveAll(item => !item.Contains("Test"))`